# facebook login with javascript - server related issues?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm experiencing issues with login into FB account with javascript from our website.
The login is simple, we defined the scope: email, user_birthdate, ... what we need.

On one server I can all the info we need, on another only basic information, ie: birthdate is missing and hometown as well.
Is there any way to prevent this? It might be I missed something out.
Thanks for your suggestions.

```
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
     appId      : fb_app_id, // App ID
     apiKey     : fb_app_secret,
     channelURL : '', // Channel File, not required so leave empty
     status     : false, // check login status
     cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
     xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
     frictionlessRequests : true
   });
    function login(){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if(response.status === 'connected' 
           || response.authResponse != null){
            FB_response(response);
        }
        else{
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if(response.authResponse) {
                    //alert('connected' );
                    FB_response(response);
                }
                else {
                    // user is not logged in
                }
         },{scope:'email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_location'});

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you try it with different users... All admin/tester/developer users of an app can give their permissions without the app being reviewed yet. All other users can't, and therefore you only see the basic info.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login#do-you-need-review